# How to influence oracle cardinality of inline view / CTE result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I often face an issue writing Oracle SQL queries, where the optimizer makes questionable choices re cardinality. Consider the following:

```
select t.*
from t
     join (select ...
           from ...
           where ...) t2 on t2.col = t.col;
```

The actual query text is not that important, it's more the structure. What I'm wondering is how to tell the optimizer that I know for example that even though it thinks t2 will result in 2 million rows, in fact, it might be more like 1 thousand.

To be clear, it's the cardinality of the inline view I'm trying to influence, not that of a constituent table.

I am aware of the cardinality and opt_estimate hints and have used them successfully but only for static tables, not inline views or CTEs. I'm thinking it may involve the qb_name hint and have had some success with this, but not in this particular case.

Comment: There is an undocumented cardinality hint you can try: `/*+ cardinality(t2, 500 ) */ `

Comment: Doh. Totally works. Did not realise that. Nice.